# getBody empty in Laravel 4.2 Mail::queue

Tags: laravel-4, mailgun

I send emails through `Mail::queue` on **Laravel 4.2** ; everything works fine. I use templates and the emails i receive are exactly what I want. At some point in the process I'd like to get back the body to add it to a specific table for logs purpose ; **nothing works**.

```
    // We will queue the email (we could add a protection here)
    Mail::queue($template, $template_data, function($message) use ($email, $subject, $user, $profile, $additional_mailgun_variables)
{

    // We prepare the email trace
    $email_trace = new EmailTrace;
    $email_trace->recipient = $email;
    $email_trace->subject = $subject;
    $email_trace->user_id = $user->id;
    $email_trace->user_profile_id = $profile->id;
    $email_trace->prepared_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // We prepare the MailGun variables
    $mailgun_variables = [

    'user_id' => (int) $user->id,
    'profile_id' => (int) $profile->id,
    'email_trace_id' => (int) $email_trace->id,

    ];

    // Is there any additional variable ?
    if ($additional_mailgun_variables !== NULL) $mailgun_variables += $additional_mailgun_variables;

    // We encode it
    $encoded_mailgun_variables = json_encode($mailgun_variables);

    // We finally send the email with all the correct headers
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', $encoded_mailgun_variables);

    // We get the body of the message
    $email_trace->content = $message->getBody();
    $email_trace->save();

});
```

The only problem here is the `message->getBody()` which returns `null` ; nobody has posted this problem before so i'm wondering if i'm the only one to be unable to get the `body` of the email itself when it has been processed ...

I past you the whole `Mail::queue` process in case there'd be something I do wrong here.

Thank you guys ;)

NOTE : I'm using MailGun to send emails, i don't think it will change anything to the problem tho ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the problem wouldn't appear with a `Mail::send` and tried to understand what's happening with this `Mail::queue` ...

Seems like the body (`$message->getBody()`) isn't processed/available until the very end of the queue process so it was impossible to get it.

I tried to find ways to get this `body` but it sounds technically impossible to have a clean solution with this `queue` system (NOTE : very bad impression of Laravel's flexibility here.)

I managed to emulate a first time the equivalent of what Laravel does to process this template and send it through `Swift Message`. I just render it as a view and put it within a `$body` variable.

```
// We resolve the body for the email trace logs
$body_preparation = View::make($template, $template_data);
$body = $body_preparation->render();

// We will queue the email (we could add a protection here)
Mail::queue($template, $template_data, function($message) use ($email, $subject, $body, $user, $profile, $additional_mailgun_variables)
{

    // We prepare the email trace
    $email_trace = new EmailTrace;
    $email_trace->recipient = $email;
    $email_trace->subject = $subject;

    if ($user !== NULL) $email_trace->user_id = $user->id;
    if ($profile !== NULL) $email_trace->user_profile_id = $profile->id;

    $email_trace->prepared_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if ($profile !== NULL) $profile_id = $profile->id; else $profile_id = NULL;
    if ($user !== NULL) $user_id = $user->id; else $profile_id = NULL;

    $email_trace->content = $body;
    $email_trace->save();

    // We prepare the MailGun variables
    $mailgun_variables = [

        'user_id' => (int) $user_id,
        'profile_id' => (int) $profile_id,
        'email_trace_id' => (int) $email_trace->id,

    ];

    // Is there any additional variable ?
    if ($additional_mailgun_variables !== NULL) $mailgun_variables += $additional_mailgun_variables;

    // We encode it
    $encoded_mailgun_variables = json_encode($mailgun_variables);

    // We finally send the email with all the correct headers
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', $encoded_mailgun_variables);

});
```

If anyone got the same problem, I think it's a good solution :)

Comment: This method needs to be repeated on all locations of Mail::queue is being called. Have a look on this method I discovered http://stackoverflow.com/a/34188486/366962